# TUIO #ifndef WIN32 gets ignored

Tags: winapi, ifndef

I am using the TUIO framework in Visual Studio 2013. When I build, the error 'pthread.h no such file or directory' appears. It seems TUIO runs on Linux and Windows and the `#ifndef WIN32` checks for the operating system. While Visual seems to get it right it still gives the error when I build.

See image below:

[image]

Comment: You have to define the `WIN32` preprocessor symbol yourself. While a default-generated 32-bit application using Visual Studio's wizard does define it (*Configuration Properties* → *C/C++* → *Preprocessor*: *Preprocessor Definitions*), a 64-bit application does not. You need to add it to your project settings for a 64-bit application (or a 32-bit application that wasn't generated using the Visual Studio new project wizard).

Comment: I added WIN32 to Preprocessor Definitions and it works now. Thanks!